# Does it sound too formal to say "Please be aware that..." to a friend?

Tags: expressions

I searched on google and someone says that is used in a very formal way. So I was wondering what could an alternative to saying so politely to a friend. Thank you!

Comment: 'Please be aware that you're standing on my toe'  → 'You're standing on my toe, John.'

Comment: You can substitute other *softeners* like "Remember," "You know," "Say," and even "Oh."

Comment: ***Ow!! That's my toe, you big lump!***

Comment: @EdwinAshworth ( sorry, even your suggestion sounds a little formal for the circumstances ;) )

Comment: I would limit "please be aware that" to written communications.  I cannot imagine saying it to someone in person.

Answer (score 2):

It's more that it's for formal *circumstances* (I often use quite "formal" English with one particular friend, but this is *not* the sort of thing we say).

I can't really offer a specific alternative without knowing what you're trying to tell your friend, but a couple of slightly more relaxed examples:

- ***Before we go, I need to** [tell, warn, ...] **you that** I won't be able to stay for dinner.*
- ***By the way**, I just found out I'm allergic to shellfish, **so please could we** not go to Loch Fyne.*

and last but not least [credit: @EdwinAshworth]:

- *[name or **Oi**]**, you're** standing on my toe!*